# Get a single S3 notification for multipart upload

Tags: amazon-s3

I am using S3 Event notification feature. In my case I am doing multipart upload in my S3 bucket which gives me notification for every file part that is uploaded.

Is there a way I can get a single notification once all the file parts are uploaded instead of getting multiple notifications?

Thank You,
Prasad

Comment: You should not be getting notifications of each part.  Those should never trigger notifications.  Can you capture one or two of these events and show us the structure?

Comment: What is your trigger? Is it set to "ObjectCreate (All)" or "Put"?

Comment: When I am using ObjectCreate(All), I am getting 32 different notifications for every file created. And While using Put trigger I am not receiving any notification at all.

Comment: Do you have a solution how to avoid  notification for every file part that is uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer you are looking for:

> When you configure an Amazon S3 event notification, you specify which
> supported Amazon S3 event types (such as PUT, POST, COPY, and
> **CompleteMultipartUpload**) cause Amazon S3 to send the notification. If an event type that you didn't specify occurs in your S3 bucket,
> Amazon S3 doesn't send the notification (and doesn't trigger your
> Lambda function).

Look for the event type **CompleteMultipartUpload** and see if that solves the scenario.

Ref:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-configure-s3-event-notification/